# How to handle context menu commands on items in TreeView

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am implementing an explorer-type view: on the left is a TreeView and on the right is a details view / editor view of the item selected on the left.

The TreeView contains different types of 'leaf' objects. I have defined HierarchialDataTemplates to define how the objects are presented and which context menu should be presented. The MenuItems have Commands which are bound to the view-model.

What I am struggling with is where to implement the Command handlers. The straight-forward place would be in the 'leaf' view-models but they don't know anything about the 'explorer' view-model and how to open the details/editor view.

The simplest solution would be to bind the leaf context menu to the explorer view-model as this is where the action is best executed.

How is this normally handled? Are there any 'well-known' patterns?

Comment: Imho, You should bind to the explorer view-model - which is, in your case, some kind of manager for the 'leaf' view-models. There is nothing wrong with this solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer to this question - [Bind to parent DataContext within DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594438/bind-to-parent-datacontext-within-datatemplate) - which put me on the right track.

The `UserControl` get a name and the command binding references this - `Source={x:Reference uc}}`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="View.AdminWorkstationView" Name="uc">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RequiredDeviceViewModel}">
        <DockPanel>
            <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding DataContext.EditDeviceCommand, Source={x:Reference uc}}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                              Header="Edit device" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </DockPanel.ContextMenu>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>
```