# Binding DataContext.Property to control value

Tags: c#, wpf

I make a DataGrid have DataGridCheckBoxColumn. I want to binding the CheckedAll property of DataContext to IsChecked of checkbox in DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate.

Here is my Data row item class:

```
public class ContractForMuster : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _Checked;
    public bool Checked
    {
        get
        {
            return _Checked;
        }
        set
        {
            _Checked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Checked");
        }
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string ContractCode { get; set; }

    public string Fullname { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my DataContext class:

```
public class ContractForMusters : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _CheckedAll;
    public bool CheckedAll
    {
        get
        {
            return _CheckedAll;
        }
        set
        {
            _CheckedAll = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CheckedAll");
        }
    }
    public List<ContractForMuster> models { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Code behide:

```
viewModel = new ContractForMusters();
entities = new List<ContractForMuster>();
entities.Add(entity); //Code add
viewModel.models = entities;
viewModel.CheckedAll = true;
this.DataContext = viewModel;
```

And XAML code:

```
<DataGrid Name="DgdContract" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding models}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn MaxWidth="50" MinWidth="30" Binding="{Binding Checked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="ChkAll" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="DgdContractCheckBoxItemChkAll_Click" IsChecked="{Binding ?}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Control.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="5 0 0 0" />
                    <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Click" Handler="DgdContractCheckBoxItem_Click" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource IDAlignmentAlign}" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" />

        <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellAlignmentAlign}" Binding="{Binding ContractCode}" Header="Contract Code" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" />

        <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellAlignmentAlign}" Binding="{Binding Fullname}" Header="Fullname" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How to can I binding property CheckedAll to IsChecked of checkbox ChkAll?

Thanks!

Comment: I had found a a method to solve this problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594438/bind-to-parent-datacontext-within-datatemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

In Window element, add x:Name="root", then in checkbox:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ChkAll" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="DgdContractCheckBoxItemChkAll_Click" IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.CheckedAll, ElementName=root}" />
```

Thanks All!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind directly to the datacontext of the root.
Something like this (untested):

(Root of your document)

```
<Window ... x:Name="root">
```

(Your element)

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ChkAll" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          Click="DgdContractCheckBoxItemChkAll_Click" 
          DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}" 
          IsChecked="{Binding CheckedAll}" />
```

Comment: But if I using root property, I can't using INotifyPropertyChanged for CheckAll property. Ofcourse, I can find control ChkAll with code and set check for it, but I don't want using this method.